how to infer a custom pretrained model using mmdet?
I'm trying to run masa with some custom model (tuned yolov5xu fwiw) trained on some external dataset. I'm struggling to understand how do I run it using mdmdet framework. Documentation seems a bit unclear for me as it states I need to have some kind of config-file for it, but it is surprising as

I'm not going to train one, I simple need to model().predict()
Config file contains a lot of details I'm not very familiar with. Making this huge config file for simple run looks like overhead.

While it is extremely simple to infer yolo using native api
model = YOLO('model.pt')
results = model.predict('video.mp4',save=True)

so far it seems overcomplicated to do so with mmdet.
Does anybody know if I could really plug my model to mmdet easily?
I've tried to make config smth like
model = dict(
    type='YOLOX',
    backbone=dict(
        init_cfg=dict(type='Pretrained', checkpoint='/path/to/yolo.pt')
    )
)
load_from='/path/to/yolo.pt'

but it seems to be not enough to run. It asks some additional fields in config
